# LUIS - proper nouns mixed with adjective(s) and partial entity matches

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I have two hierarchical entities like this (simplified): "Order::OpenOrder, Order::AnyOrder, Job::OpenJob, Job::AnyJob" for a search application.  I'm trying to train LUIS to correctly understand inputs like (a)"acme open orders", (b)"open acme orders", (c)"acme open jobs", (d)"open acme jobs" using utterances.

If I just use the two simplest utterances "open orders" -> Order::OpenOrder and "open jobs" -> Job:::OpenJob, then inputs (a) and (c) work fine.  But example (b) finds Order::Open, but the string "acme" is included in the entity character range.  Example (d) is unable to resolve any entities.

Complicating things is that it's also legal to just input "acme orders" or "acme jobs", where I've trained LUIS using utterances like "blah orders" and "blah jobs" where "orders" and "jobs" are mapped to Order:AnyOrder, Job::AnyJob, respectively.  And then you can also just input things like "orders", "open Orders", etc.

Anyway, none of this is working consistently and I'm wondering if I'm taking the wrong approach to training LUIS to understand adjective-noun pairs where proper nouns can appear between them.  Anyone else had a model like this who could share some advice?

Thanks,

-Erik

Comment: Could you perhaps be more specific by providing some examples of data that are recognized correctly and some that are not?

Comment: General advice is to definitely add more utterances to improve the accuracy in prediction of both intents and entities. You should have at least 15 utterances per intent, however more may be needed if you are also needing to consider adding utterances that are "valuable" in the sense that in the example utterances that contain your entity, make sure you include utterances of the entity being in different places within the context (syntax, word order, etc.). With too few examples, LUIS won't be able to learn as well

Comment: Also here's a link to best practices when building your LUIS app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-best-practices that may be helpful as well. You may also consider perhaps adding patterns too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-pattern

Comment: @Zeryth Thanks for the advice.  I've been working with LUIS further and can't get it trained to recognize an entity when the mapped words don;t appear in the input consecutively.  So "show me acme open orders" finds the order:open entity, but "show me open acme orders" only sees the "order" entity, which oddly gets matched with the substring "acme orders".

I've tried a lot of utterances and some patterns.  I don't see how to setup a pattern to recognize an entity that does appear as consecutive words.

Comment: @ErikJohnson I feel like hierarchical entities are not the way to go here with how you're using them, b/c although both of your children entities are of Order type, they are actually not related to each other in the context of a single utterance--specifically in an utterance it seems like you're going to find either one type of order or the other, not both. Docs on when to use hierarchical: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-quickstart-intent-and-hier-entity#purpose-of-the-app-with-this-entity

Comment: Additionally, not having access to your language model, I can only speak generally, but be sure to follow what's outlined in the Best Practices docs that I linked you to earlier, specifically with “Define distinct intents”. For example since Open Jobs and Open Order have the same vocabulary “Open”, then maybe have an intent of “Open” and then have Job and Order as simple entities. Then provide ample utterances where open is in different places of word order. And be sure to not have overlapping intents, so make a separate intent for the other scenarios like “GetAny”, for example